# Jquery each question

Tags: jquery

I have a quick question that I need some help with if possible. Am I able to have more than one input with the same id and loop through the values of these? Something similar to the code below:

```
<p>ID:<input name="check_id" type="hidden" id="check_id"  value="1"/></p>
        <p>ID:<input name="check_id" type="hidden" id="check_id"  value="2"/></p>

jQuery("#check_id").each(function(){
var check_data = jQuery(this).val();
alert(check_data); 
});
```

Thanks

Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. IDs must be unique. You will likely only select the first.

You could possibly do something like this, though it is less efficient:

```
jQuery("input[id=check_id]").each(function(){
    var check_data = jQuery(this).val();
    alert(check_data); 
});
```

But if you're going to do that, you might as well fix your IDs to be unique, and select by the `name` attribute.

```
jQuery("input[name=check_id]").each(function(){
    var check_data = jQuery(this).val();
    alert(check_data); 
});
```

If all the `<input>` elements you want are contained in a container, you could speed things up by specifying that container.

```
jQuery("#myContainer input[name=check_id]").each(function(){
    var check_data = jQuery(this).val();
    alert(check_data); 
});
```

This code example presumes there is a common ancestor with the ID `myContainer`.

---

**EDIT:** With regard to your question in the comment below, `return false;` inside an `.each()` loop only exits the loop. You could however set a flag that will tell the subsequent code whether or not to execute.

Something like this:

```
var shouldContinue = true;

jQuery("#myContainer input[name=check_id]").each(function(){
    var check_data = jQuery(this).val();
    if( someCondition ) {
        shouldContinue = false; // signal to not execute subsequent code
        return false;  // Halt the loop
    }
});

if( shouldContinue ) {
     // execute code if shouldContinue is true
}
```

Comment: Hi Patrick, is it possible to stop the remainder of my script running using return false inside the loop or does that only stop the remaining loops?

Comment: @Paul - Inside an `.each()` loop, `return false;` will only stop the loop. You could however set a variable to signal whether the code after the loop should execute. I'll update my answer with an example.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Patrick. That worked great. Paul

Answer (score 0):

In HTML, ids are **unique**. So no, you will just get a single object when using the `#..` selector. Which one that is when you have assigned a single id multiple times is not defined; actually you should fix that!

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of the [HTML `id` attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_standard_id.asp) is that it is supposed to be unique.

Perhaps you want to use [classes](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_standard_class.asp) instead? For example, consider the following:

```
<p>ID:<input name="check_id" type="hidden" class="check_id" value="1" /></p>
<p>ID:<input name="check_id" type="hidden" class="check_id" value="2" /></p>

...

jQuery(".check_id").each(function() {
    var check_data = jQuery(this).val();
    alert(check_data); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `id` attribute (which as others have said, must be unique in a document) and use a [attribute-equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to select by name, like this:

```
jQuery("input[name=check_id]").each(function() {
  var check_data = jQuery(this).val();
  alert(check_data); 
});
```

Or add `class="check_id"` (still removing the `id="check_id"`) and use a class selector, like this:

```
jQuery(".check_id").each(function() {
  var check_data = jQuery(this).val();
  alert(check_data); 
});
```

Comment: I wonder if it is quicker in IE to select using the attribute-equals selector, since it doesn't need to split apart the potential multiple class names. Any thoughts?

Comment: Thanks that is exactly what I was trying to do. Thank you for taking the time to reply

Comment: @patrick - Possibly, but the `className` is on every element, whereas `name` is undefined and jumps out early, so I'm not sure, would have test it out, though testing in older IE scares me :)

Comment: Nick - Good point. Maybe I'll do a little testing one of these days. I'll leave a note here if I get around to it. :o)